# ASP.NET and C# async

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm confused about C# **async**. I understand **async** for parallel task processing. For example, a method does A and B task, and **async** enables A and B do action in the same time; B doesn't have to wait until A be done.

But the below example code does only a single task which is pulling data from a database. It means, there is nothing for parallel tasks. But why does it use **async**?

Please give me an advice so that I can understand **async**.

```
[ResponseType(typeof(BookDetailDTO))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetBook(int id)
{
    var book = await db.Books.Include(b => b.Author).Select(b =>
        new BookDetailDTO()
        {
            Id = b.Id,
            Title = b.Title,
            Year = b.Year,
            Price = b.Price,
            AuthorName = b.Author.Name,
            Genre = b.Genre
        }).SingleOrDefaultAsync(b => b.Id == id);
    if (book == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(book);
}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx

Comment: it's the best article / explanation, especially 'Threads' section - it's clarify what you misunderstood.

Comment: Just for the record "async enables A and B do action in the same time;" is *not* correct. In most cases it's not *at the same* time. A better way to put is to think about it as "async/awaits is a synctactic sugar which makes it easy to make the program do A while it waits for the results of B without writing complicated code"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I explain this in detail in my [async ASP.NET article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx). In summary, `async` works by freeing up threads, so those threads can be used for other things.

> means, there is nothing for parallel tasks. But why does it use async?

It's true that *this request* does not do multiple things concurrently; making it async does not speed up the request at all.

However, the application as a whole *does* have other things to do; specifically, it has other requests it can respond to. Using `async` frees up thread pool threads whenever they're not being actively used. This allows your application to scale (assuming your backend is scalable). In other words, `async` allows you to make maximum use of the thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

It uses aysnc because connecting to the database and getting a response could take some time and if it was done synchronously the application would be locked in a waiting state all that time.

By making the call asynchronous the application is free to do something else while the request is sent to the database and the data returned.

Answer (score -3):

If you mark a function as `async` and then call it using the `await`-keyword at another point in your program, then the thread which called the async method doesn't block the execution of your program and can get suspended until it receives your answer.

That way i.e. your whole UI doesn't freeze up while you are pulling data from your database.

Comment: This answer would be perfectly correct if this were a client application. However, for ASP.NET, this answer is wrong; `async` does not cause an HTTP response to be sent.

Comment: @StephenCleary oh, you are right; I totally missed the ASP.NET-tag. That way, my answer isn't really fitting...